# Remove one row per sub-set conditionally

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Goal: remove the biggest value (slowest time) from each subset (column `Model`) from Dataframe.

DataFrame:

```
    Model              Time
1   bert-base-uncased  6.570979
2   bert-base-uncased  11.570979
3   bert-base-uncased  6.788779
4   albert-large-v1    5.785576
5   albert-large-v1    5.603203
6   albert-large-v1    9.727373
```

Desired Dataframe:

```
    Model              Time
1   bert-base-uncased  6.570979
2   bert-base-uncased  6.788779
3   albert-large-v1    5.785576
4   albert-large-v1    5.603203
```

---

Code:

```
subsets = df['Model']
for s in subsets:
    df[s]
```

Please let me know if there's anything else I can add to post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution for remove all maximals values per groups by [`GroupBy.transform`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html) with `max` and compare for not equal by [`Series.ne`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.ne.html), filter in [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
print (df)
               Model       Time
1  bert-base-uncased   6.570979
2  bert-base-uncased  11.570979
3  bert-base-uncased   6.788779
2  bert-base-uncased  11.570979 <- added another maximum per bert-base-uncased 
4    albert-large-v1   5.785576
5    albert-large-v1   5.603203
6    albert-large-v1   9.727373

df1 = df[df['Time'].ne(df.groupby('Model')['Time'].transform('max'))]
print (df1)
               Model      Time
1  bert-base-uncased  6.570979
3  bert-base-uncased  6.788779
4    albert-large-v1  5.785576
5    albert-large-v1  5.603203
```

If need remove only first maximum add condition:

```
df2 = (df[df['Time'].ne(df.groupby('Model')['Time'].transform('max')) | 
          df['Time'].duplicated()])
print (df2)
               Model       Time
1  bert-base-uncased   6.570979
3  bert-base-uncased   6.788779
2  bert-base-uncased  11.570979
4    albert-large-v1   5.785576
5    albert-large-v1   5.603203
```

Comment: This answer worked for me! Thanks :) Will accept in 7 mins

Answer (score 3):

You can `drop` the max rows per group identified with `idxmax`:

```
df.drop(df.groupby('Model')['Time'].idxmax().values)
```

output:

```
               Model      Time
1  bert-base-uncased  6.570979
3  bert-base-uncased  6.788779
4    albert-large-v1  5.785576
5    albert-large-v1  5.603203
```

Comment: This is concise. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use a groupby and a slice:

```py
df = df.groupby('Model').apply(lambda sub_df: sub_df.sort_values('Time').iloc[:-1]).reset_index(drop=True)
```

Comment: This game me a non propagated column of Model

Comment: @StressedBoi_69420 Fixed, I was missing dropping the group key from the index

Comment: This is working now. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can `groupby` "Model", and use `idxmax` method to find the index of the max time in each group. Then using `Index.isin` method, filter out the indices of these values.

```
max_time_indices = df.groupby('Model')['Time'].idxmax()
out = df[~df.index.isin(max_time_indices)]
```

Output:

```
               Model      Time
1  bert-base-uncased  6.570979
3  bert-base-uncased  6.788779
4    albert-large-v1  5.785576
5    albert-large-v1  5.603203
```

Comment: it's too bad to use `isin` if you already have the indices ;) [I used `drop`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70680089/16343464)

Comment: @mozway didn't realize you had the same approach :-)